# Streamlit st.write_stream function removes all newline characters in the response stream

Tags: streamlit

I have the following text:

```
Here is a new recipe for Chicken Biryani using the ingredients provided:    

Chicken Dum Biryani  

Prep Time: 30 mins Cook Time: 30 mins Servings: 2  

Ingredients:

2 bone-in chicken thighs (about 1 lb total), skin removed
1 cup basmati rice, rinsed
1 small onion, finely chopped
2 garlic cloves, minced
1 tbsp ginger, minced
```

I am using `st.write_stream` to create that typewriter effect(streaming) which should render the text exactly as shown. However, streamlit's `st.write_stream` doesn't honor the newlines and prints the stream as follows

```
Here is a new recipe for Chicken Biryani using the ingredients provided: Chicken Dum Biryani Prep Time: 30 mins Cook Time: 30 mins Servings: 2 Ingredients: 2 bone-in chicken thighs (about 1 lb total), skin removed 1 cup basmati rice, rinsed 1 small onion, finely chopped 2 garlic cloves, minced 1 tbsp ginger, minced
```

Here is my code

```py
response = """
Here is a new recipe for Chicken Biryani using the ingredients provided:    

Chicken Dum Biryani  

Prep Time: 30 mins Cook Time: 30 mins Servings: 2  

Ingredients:

2 bone-in chicken thighs (about 1 lb total), skin removed
1 cup basmati rice, rinsed
1 small onion, finely chopped
2 garlic cloves, minced
1 tbsp ginger, minced
"""
def stream_data():
    for word in _LOREM_IPSUM.split():
        yield word + " "
        time.sleep(0.02)


if st.button("Stream data"):
    st.write(stream_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.split` with no argument, [it splits on all whitespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (`" "`, `"\n"`, `"\t"`, ...). Also, consecutive whitespaces are regarded as a single separator.

```py
# No space, no "\n" in the result.
>>> "Chicken Dum Biryani\n\nPrep Time: 30 mins".split()
['Chicken', 'Dum', 'Biryani', 'Prep', 'Time:', '30', 'mins']
```

What you need is simply to split on spaces:

```py
RESPONSE = """
Here is a new recipe for Chicken Biryani using the ingredients provided:

Chicken Dum Biryani

Prep Time: 30 mins Cook Time: 30 mins Servings: 2

Ingredients:

2 bone-in chicken thighs (about 1 lb total), skin removed
1 cup basmati rice, rinsed
1 small onion, finely chopped
2 garlic cloves, minced
1 tbsp ginger, minced
"""

import time
import streamlit as st


def stream_data():
    for word in RESPONSE.split(" "):
        yield word + " "
        time.sleep(0.02)


if st.button("Stream data"):
    st.write(stream_data)
```

and it gives:

[image]